# How to fix a Mac base conda environment when sqlite3 is broken

Tags: python, sqlite, conda

I recently updated the Python version of my base conda environment from 3.8 to 3.9, using `mamba update python=3.9`, but I can no longer run IPython, because the sqlite3 package appears to be broken.

```
python
Python 3.9.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:55:37) 
[Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/rosborn/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/Users/rosborn/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/rosborn/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: (_sqlite3_enable_load_extension)
  Referenced from: '/Users/rosborn/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so'
  Expected in: '/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib'
```

Since I had another Python 3.9 environment that is still functional, I tried copying over the `envs/py39/lib/sqlite3.36.0` and `envs/py39/lib/python3.9/sqlite3` directories, as well as `envs/py39/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so` because I assumed the sqlite3 libraries had been incorrectly compiled, but that doesn't fix the problem.

On the Homebrew Github, there was a [related issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/49731), where someone suggested checking whether the missing symbol was there. It seems to be all present and correct.

```
$ nm -gj /Users/rosborn/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so | grep enable_load_extension 
_sqlite3_enable_load_extension
```

I don't know how Homebrew installs sqlite3, but the remaining fixes seemed to require checking the system libsqlite, which I don't have administrative access to. In case it's relevant, I am on an Intel Mac, so it's not related to the M1 chip, as some related issues appear to be.

Does the conda distribution attempt to link to the system libsqlite? If so, why does this problem not affect the `py39` environment?

Any tips will be welcome. If it were not the base environment, I would just delete the one with the problem and start again. I attempted a forced reinstall of sqlite3, but it appeared not to be installable as a separate package.

Comment: DLL issues are often due to [mixing channels](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels). Make sure all your packages in **base** come from one place (presumably Conda Forge, since you're using Mamba). Generally, one should not be using the **base** environment for work, e.g., running Jupyter. It's best left alone as only for Conda-related infrastructure.

Comment: @merv, Thanks for the comment. After many years of using conda, I was unaware of the recommendation to do all your work in other environments, although it makes a lot of sense and would have prevented the need to start all over again a couple of times in the past. The only issue I see is on machines where users share a common distribution because it requires making them switch environments. I will certainly take the advice in your link to enforce strict channel priorities.

Comment: As a quick follow-up, after modifying my .condarc file as recommended in the above link to enforce channel priority (with condo-forge on top), I tried doing another update of my base environment to Python 3.10. This had exactly the same issue, i.e., it complains of the missing symbol in /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib.  I wonder if the bug is actually in the condo-forge distribution. so that I should have required the default channel in the update. I'll post a question on the conda-forge gitter site.

Comment: What does `conda list '(libsqlite|python)'` show? The `python` package itself provides the `_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so` file, and the Conda Forge v3.9.15 builds specify `libsqlite >=3.40.0,<4.0a0` (might explain why the copying hack failed). When I install the latest `conda-forge/osx-64::python=3.9.15=h709bd14_0_cpython` build, and inspect the `_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so` with `otool -L` the sqlite3 entry is: `@rpath/libsqlite3.0.dylib`, which implies it is not linked to the system. Either something like LD_LIBRARY_PATH is weird, or you need to force reinstall `libsqlite`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. It seems that doing `mamba install libsqlite --force-reinstall` worked. I had been looking for a sqlite3 package, and hadn't realized that `libsqlite` could be installed separately.

Comment: to those who don't use mamba but counter same issue, `conda install libsqlite --force-reinstall`  solve this iusse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the suggestions by @merv, the solution to this problem was to force a reinstall of the `libsqlite` package.

```
$ mamba install libsqlite --force-reinstall
```

After updating Python, it seems that `sqlite3` was linked to the Mac system library, `/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib`, rather than one installed by conda-forge. According to [discussions elsewhere](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik-support/issues/119), it is likely that Apple disables the missing `_sqlite3_enable_load_extension` extension for security reasons, leading to the observed error message. I don't know why the link error occurred in the first place, but fortunately, conda distributes `libsqlite` as a separate package, so the fix was simple to implement.

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same issue for miniconda; in this case the solution was

```
conda install libsqlite --force-reinstall -y
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this clarification. Mamba is a drop-in replacement for most conda commands, so 'conda' for 'mamba' are usually interchangeable, but I probably should have made that clear.