# Error message when import package with Miniconda environment

Tags: python, pandas

I have installed Miniconda and create from this a env named data.

Then I tried to do something simple:

```
import pandas as pd
```

but get this error message from Vscode.

Any idea ?

```
Échec du démarrage du Kernel. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.core.application import (  # type:ignore[attr-defined]
  File "/Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 15, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell
  File "/Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 73, in <module>
    from IPython.core.history import HistoryManager
  File "/Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 11, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension
  Referenced from: <1B6E2CAC-D818-304D-9C3C-B2E32B00D8B7> /Users/jacques/miniconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Expected in:     <567CDD63-191D-36E4-959B-7DE47C7AFD7A> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib. 
Pour plus d’informations, consultez Jupyter log.
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why your import of pandas is triggering that message. I wonder if you didn't troubleshoot well enough to get at the specific cause there or if in truncating your shared traceback, you left out pertinent info. Anyway, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74837553/8508004) looks pertinent to your error. (Perhaps, the answer in the link in blue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77446827/8508004) might help you in understanding what happened to trigger what you are seeing, too.)

Comment: Please [edit] to add a translation. I'm not fluent in French, but it's something like: "Error starting the kernel. ... For more information, see Jupyter log."

Comment: Notice that the traceback doesn't show your `import` line or even mention `pandas`, so this error has nothing to do with the import; if you did `print('hello')` instead, you'd get the same error. (FYI @Wayne) If you want to [edit] in light of that, please do. And to be clear, the kernel that it's referring to is IPykernel, which is the backend you're using with Jupyter.

Comment: @Wayne, thx it seems that `conda install libsqlite --force-reinstall -y` works fine and I don't get the error message anymore.

Comment: @wjandrea, you were right. Even a `print('hello')` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For the record...
From the commennts, [this solution to a similar traceback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75821180/8508004) helped in this case:

```bash
conda install libsqlite --force-reinstall -y
```